# draw cross symbol using jquery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I have created div element on run type using Javascript to draw a different type of shape. I am using jquery and CSS to draw shape and using like this in my project. the below code for Diamond.

```
$(symbol).css({

    "width": options.ShapeSize.width/2,
    "height": options.ShapeSize.height/2,
    "left": (evt.startX),
    "top": (evt.startY),
    "border-style": "solid",
    "background-color": options.Style.Color,
    "border-color": options.Style.BorderColor,
    "margin": "3px 0 0 30px",
    "transform": "rotate(-45deg)",
    "transform-origin": "0 100%",
  });
```

Same like I want to draw cross symbol (**+**) using jquery and CSS. I refered the beow link. http://jsbin.com/defigayimace/1/edit. In that, they are using CSS only. But i want to append CSS styles with jquery to draw shape.

Anyone help me?

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: what's wrong with using only css for this? it's a clean and easy solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [drawing CSS cross shape with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932008/drawing-css-cross-shape-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do that with CSS?

Won't a simple HTML entity for a "Heavy Greek cross" suffice: ✚ `&#x271A;`?

[See more HTML entities](http://character-code.com/special-character-html-codes.php)