# drawing CSS cross shape with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me to draw the Cross(**+**) shape using jquery code? I don't want to use CSS styles. Want to append all CSS style through jquery like the below code.

```
 $(symbol).css({
        "width": options.ShapeSize.width,
        "height": options.ShapeSize.height,
        "border-style": "solid",
        "background-color": options.Style.Color,
        "border-color": options.Style.BorderColor,
        "border-width": options.Style.BorderWidth,
    });
```

I want this shape using jquery only. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/92XTx/65/)

Comment: just out of curiosity, why don't you use jQuery to toggle a class and give the style to that class. therefore you can control the shape with jquery?

Comment: Why do you want this using jQuery only? CSS is a far more effective tool to use here.

Comment: I am using only .js file, and create all html element and append CSS styles through jquery. So i can't use CSS directly.

Comment: @Bharathi that seems to be a big mistake...

Comment: Then for browser compatibility you're going to have to add the browser prefixed versions of each css styles in your script and it's definitely going to look ugly.. BTW why did you post the question twice?

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform:rotate(...deg)`

```
#cross {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

### OR

Use this piece of jQuery and also add other css properties like this

```
$("#cross").css({width: "100px",
   height: "100px",
   position: "relative"
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/92XTx/66/)

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/92XTx/71/)

Comment: Thank you. But, I want to draw( + ) symbol.. not multiply symbol. See my question. I want to draw plus symbol using jquery only.